# Sending array of longs to MVC Action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, .net-core-3.1

I'm currently struggling to send an array of long's to an .NET Core MVC Action. I get an error 400.

What I'm trying to achieve is to send the array of longs [1,2,3,...] to the action and then return data but it's just not triggering.

> errors: {$: [,…]} $: [,…] 0: "The input does not contain any JSON
> tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when
> isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine:
> 0." status: 400 title: "One or more validation errors occurred." traceId: "|9434a014-4b2c198fc0bb7bd6." type:
> "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet("SchedulesById")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetSchedulesById(long[] ids)
    {
        //Get data from database

        return new JsonResult(null);
    }
```

**Javscript function**
//id is the array.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var jsonData = { ids: array };
console.log(jsonData);

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "../API/Schedules/SchedulesById/",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("Schedule: Success [" + id + "]");
        console.log(data);

    },
    failure: function () {
        console.log("Schedule [" + id + "]: Failed.");         
    },
    statusCode: {
        500: function () {
            console.log("Schedule [" + id + "]: Failed.");               
        }
    }
```